# Is there a method in verilog to start reading ROM data from a specific address?

Tags: verilog

I've designed a ROM for coefficients and an up-down counter to read these coefficients one by one but there are two cases for the starting point where a specific number of coefficients for type1 and another set of coefficients for type 2 ... so for example for type 1 I want to start from address zero and for type 2 start from address 30 ... I remember that someone told me it is possible using some # or something but I don't remember what is the actual way to do this

this for my counter code

```
module UDcounter(input clk,rst,up,GItype,
                 output reg [5:0]addr); 

always @(posedge clk,posedge rst)
if (rst)
      addr<=6'b0;
 else   
    begin
      if (GItype)  //assume 1 is a long GI type
        begin
         // addr=6'b000000;
           if (up)
             addr=addr+1;
           else addr=addr-1;
         end
      else   //for short GI
        begin
          //addr=6'b100000;
          if (up)
          addr=addr+1;
          else addr=addr-1; 
        end
    end

endmodule
```

the error here is that every clock cycle it start addressing from addr=0 for example and the output address is always 1 (for the +1) line

Comment: The problem is that, apart from reset, your code has no idea when to begin. You talk about *"but there are two cases for the starting point*" followed later by *" I want to start.."* but you have nothing in there to deal with starting.

Comment: I know there  is a control signal to select one of the two cases ..if i guessed what you mean correctly

Comment: you have a solution in your code commented out.  You can play with it. On the side note, you misused blocking assignments there.

Answer (score 0):

So what I understood from your question is that you want to design a ROM which will store coefficients.
Going by your question I assume that you have two types of coefficient viz type a & type b stored in the ROM, say the starting address for type a is 0 and for type b is 30. To go about accessing the ROM you would want two counters viz addr_ptr_a and addr_ptr_b which will act as address pointers, lets assume that the ROM has about 60 address locations then addr_ptr_a will count from 0 to 29 and addr_ptr_b will count from 30 to 60. 
The GItype signal can be used to determine which counter to enable.
I am assuming a sequential read operation, for a random read operation you would need a separate logic to generate the read address.